# initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting when start MySQL in kubernetes

Tags: mysql

Now I am using this command to deploy a HA mysql cluster:

```
helm install hades-mysql-ha incubator/mysqlha -n hades-pro
```

when the pod started, shows this error:

```
2021-05-20 05:54:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.29-1debian10 started.
2021-05-20 05:54:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-05-20 05:54:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.29-1debian10 started.
2021-05-20 05:54:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2021-05-20T05:54:19.866813Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-05-20T05:54:19.868861Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2021-05-20T05:54:19.868896Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I already clean the mount folder in the NAS and reinstall MySQL HA, and recreated PV, why still give this error tips? what should I do to fix it?

Comment: "MySQL cluster" is ambiguous -- NDB?  Galera?  PXC?  InnoDB Cluster?

Comment: If this is the chart [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/mysqlha) its marked as deprecated. Can you provide the chart origin and version? Check the bug reports from the origin because it looks based on the error that the initialization is incorrect.